# Removing one object from an array by its id, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```
    const arr=[]

    let id=0
    app.post('/book',(req,res)=>{
      payload={body: req.body,id: id+1}
      id=id+1
      arr.push(payload)
      console.log("arr",arr);
      return res.send("success")
    })
```

`this is how I created the push function in an array with default id

i try to delete element from this array by its id using pop or using  some loop`

Comment: Can you declare the array with `let` instead of `const`?  Because then you could just re-assign it with the result of a `.filter()` call on itself.

Comment: [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array by the [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Answer (score 3):

first of all you need to convert the id into number then use filter to delete the required element like so:

```
const deleteId = parseInt(req.body.id);

arr = arr.filter(item => item.id !== deleteId);

console.log("arr", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tested snippet which works successfully:

```js
    const arr=[]

    let id=0
    while (id < 10) {
      payload={body: "some text " + id,id: id+1}
      id=id+1
      arr.push(payload)
    }
    
    let toRemove = arr.map((item, index) => ((item.id == 3) ? index : false)).filter(item => (item !== false));
    
    if (toRemove.length) {
        for (let indexToRemove = toRemove[0]; indexToRemove < arr.length - 1; indexToRemove++) {
            arr[indexToRemove] = arr[indexToRemove + 1];
        }
        
        arr.pop();
    }
    
    console.log(arr);
```

I'm:

- mapping the items of an array to their index if the id matches and false otherwise (assuming that an id is unique)
- then filter the result by the items not being false, getting the index to remove
- then check whether the id was found
- and if so, loop the array starting from that index to the end
- and copy the next item into the current one
- except for the last element which is popped

Tested with an id of 3, you can use the value you want instead.